# How to do a Async get() request sending an array of ids, but don't want to loop through the whole async get request for array

Tags: node.js, arrays, angular, async-await, get

```
      for (let i = 0; i < this.selectedworksheets.length; i++) {
      specific_templateRowId = await this.httpClient.get < Array<number>> (`${GLOBAL.BASE_URL}/templaterow/${this.worksheetmatrixRows[i].Id}`).toPromise();
    }
```

I want to send all the array elements without looping as by looping the get request is called multiple times.
The response from backend is an array and  I want the response to be saved as one array but due to multiple get requests the array doesn't save all the responses but only the one for their own get request.

This is the API for this get request:

```
// get template_rowID
app.get('/templaterow/:ID', function (req, res) {
logging('[GET] /templaterow');

console.dir(req.params.ID);
fetched_templatewrowIDs =[];
templateID = req.params.ID

async.eachSeries(templateID, function(elem, callback) {
// Get this Vehicle from DB
let sql = `SELECT Id FROM template_row WHERE TemplateId = ${req.params.ID} AND RowNo= 1`;
 console.dir(sql);
wmsconn
    .query(sql, function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (err)            
            throw err;

     
        
        fetched_templatewrowIDs.push(JSON.stringify(rows[0].Id));
        console.log('The solution is: ', fetched_templatewrowIDs);
       
       callback();
    });

}, function(err, arrayOfTests) {
    // All SQL statements are finished
    console.log("ASYNC SERIES finished. Returning these 'newTemplaterowids' :");
    console.log("After the  callback WMS ID array ", fetched_templatewrowIDs);
    res.send(JSON.stringify(fetched_templatewrowIDs));
 });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use map and combineLatest to get all responses within the same stream.

Something like:

```
const objects = [foo, bar] 
// here response is of type Observable<T[]>
// where T is the type of a single response from your server
const response = combineLatest(objects.map(object=>this.http.get(`${API_URL}/${object.id}`))
```

Comment: The combineLatest( ) function is deprecated here. My object is like this   worksheetmatrixRows: Array < templateWMS > = [];    // It is an array of type templateWMS thus the id is an instance of each one entry of type templateWMS